# SQL Server : How to place dashes sign ( - ) between first and last record

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here I have query for select the first and last query.

```
SELECT MAX(invoiceNo) AS MaxInvoiceNo, MIN(invoiceNo) AS MinInvoiceNo FROM JobInvoice
```

My question is how I'm gonna fix this to put dash ( - ) between that `MAX(invoiceNo)` and `MIN(invoiceNo)`. Just like `MAX(invoiceNo)- MIN(invoiceNo)`

Comment: +' - '+ would give space dash space between the two values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just concatenate them.  If the values are strings:

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(MAX(invoiceNo))) + '-' + LTRIM(RTRIM(MIN(invoiceNo))) AS InvoiceRange
FROM JobInvoice;
```

If not, you need to cast them:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), MAX(invoiceNo)) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), MIN(invoiceNo)) AS InvoiceRange
FROM JobInvoice;
```

Comment: both query produce same ouput. then how about the trim?

Comment: You should use `trim()` (SQL Server 2017+) or `ltrim(rtrim())`.

Answer (score 0):

It work from Gordon's help. Here I add a bit.

```
SELECT RTRIM(MAX(invoiceNo)) + ' - ' + MIN(invoiceNo) AS InvoiceRange FROM JobInvoice
```

Output like

[image]